# Multiple different meta for marker color and marker size

Tags: pgfplots, color, metadata

How do I set the color of a marker with one meta column in a table AND its size with another meta column?

So in this minimal working example, how can I set the marker size with 'w1' and the color with 'w2'?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{temp.dat}
x y w1 w2
1 1 2 4
2 2 1 3
3 3 4 2
4 4 3 1
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot[scatter,
only marks,
scatter src=explicit,
scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark size=2+\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/300}]
table[x=x,y=y,meta=w1]{temp.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `visualization depends on=<expr>\as<macro>` key for to make another variable available. If you set `visualization depends on=\thisrow{w2}\as\wtwo`, the content of the `w2` column will be available as a macro called `\wtwo`:

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{temp.dat}
x y w1 w2
1 1 2 4
2 2 1 3
3 3 4 2
4 4 3 1
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot[
    scatter,
    only marks,
    scatter src=explicit,
    visualization depends on=\thisrow{w2}\as\wtwo,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={
        /tikz/mark size=\wtwo
    }
]
table[x=x,y=y,meta=w1]{temp.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why did you put the `filecontents*` before the `documentclass`?

Comment: @GarbageCollector: Because that's what the OP did. But you're right, I was surprised by that as well. Seems to work fine though.

Comment: There is a drawback if we put the `filecontents*` before the document class because TeX is unable to rewrite the `temp.dat` even though `\usepackage{filecontents}` exists in the preamble.

Comment: @GarbageCollector: Yeah, I know. That's not the case here, though.

Comment: @GarbageCollector: I didn't know that putting the `filecontents*` after the `documentclass` would allow Tex to overwrite the file.
@Jake: Thanks a lot, exactly what I needed!

Comment: By design, in the beginning `filecontents` environment can only be used before the `\documentclass` and it cannot overwrite the existing file. But later the developers made a hacked-up version by providing us with `filecontents` package. This package must be loaded if we want to let TeX overwrite the existing file. No need to load `filecontents` package if you just want to invoke `filecontents` environment in the preamble.

Comment: Is it possible to conduct this plot without w1?