# pgfplots: marker size relative to interval size

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am trying to create a `ybar interval` pgf plot with horizontal lines as markers on top of each interval/bar. Intervals widths are specified by my external CSV data file.

I defined my own plotmark (just a `\draw (0,0) -- (1,0);`), which I am trying to scale in width for each interval I'm plotting.

I have found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98648/31877), where the author makes use of `\thisrow`, but in my case I get an error:

> ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `thisrow_unavailable_load_table_directly'
>   (in 'thisrow_unavailable_load_table_directly').

The [pgfplots documentation](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) (p.56) mentions this error:

> The argument hcolumn namei has to denote either an existing column or one for which a column alias exists (see the manual of PgfplotsTable). If it can't be resolved, the math parser yields an \Unknown function" error message.

**How do I fix/accomplish this?**

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{hr}{
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
}

\begin{axis}[ymode=log,]
\addplot+[
    ybar interval,
    fill=cyan,
    draw=none,
    mark=hr,
    scatter,
    scatter src=explicit,
    visualization depends on=\thisrow{width}\as\intvWidth,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={
        /tikz/mark width=\intvWidth
    },
] table [
    col sep=comma,
    create on use/xaccum/.style={
        create col/expr=\pgfmathaccuma+\prevrow{width}
    },
    x=xaccum, y=height,
] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My CSV file looks like this:

```
height,width
1,884
2,5768
3,835
4,2661
5,492
6,1349
7,486
8,1117
9,498
10,854
10,0
```

And here's a rendering without widened markers (the blue specs above the cyan area are the markers now):
[image: bad markers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of scaling a marker, it might be easier to just use the `jump mark left` plot style:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
height,width
1,884
2,5768
3,835
4,2661
5,492
6,1349
7,486
8,1117
9,498
10,854
10,0
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{hr}{
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
}

\begin{axis}[ymode=log]
\addplot+[
    jump mark left, mark=none
] table [
    col sep=comma,
    create on use/xaccum/.style={
        create col/expr=\pgfmathaccuma+\prevrow{width}
    },
    x=xaccum, y=height,
] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This kills the `fill=cyan`. I *do* want the area under the marker to be filled. Is there a way to combine both?

Comment: You can use a second `\addplot` command for that (though I wouldn't recommend using a filled plot when using a logarithmic axis)

Comment: fair enough. altough, you can do it with just `\addplot[jump mark left]`